# MapServer in WMS mode for geotiff folder

Tags: qgis, wms, mapserver

I spent a few days trying to configure MapServer to work as a WMS server. I have a folder full of geotiff files (454 GB total, 62 MB per file). Each raster has embedded pyramid and I generated .vrt for that set.
This works in Geoserver, but performance is very poor. So now I am trying to do the same in MapServer (hopefully it will be much faster).

Serving shapefiles in MapServer works, but when I try to publish tif files, in QGIS I get this message:

> Invalid Layer: WMS provider Cannot calculate extent Raster layer
>   Provider is not valid (provider: wms, URI:
>   contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:3908&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=Urbane%20zone%202012&styles=&url=http://localhost:8181/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map%3DC:%5C%5Cwmstif.map

Here is my map file content:

```
MAP
   EXTENT 6304500 4709990 6635000 5027700 #Tile Cache
   TEMPLATEPATTERN "."
   SIZE 512 512
   MAXSIZE 8192
   STATUS ON
   UNITS METERS
   NAME "Test map name"
   IMAGETYPE AGG_PNG
   OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "AGG_PNG"
    DRIVER "AGG/PNG"
    MIMETYPE "image/png"
    IMAGEMODE RGBA
    TRANSPARENT ON
    EXTENSION "png"
   END
   CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "C:\ms4w\proj\nad"
   PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:3908"
   END
   WEB
      METADATA
         ows_title "Zoran example"
         ows_enable_request "*"
         ows_srs "EPSG:3908" #Recommended
         ows_abstract "This is an example WMS server from MapServer"
      END
      LOG "C:/ms.log"
   END
   LAYER
      NAME "Urbane zone 2012"
      STATUS ON
      TYPE RASTER
      UNITS METERS
      DATA "F:\geoserver_data\data\urbane_zone\index.vrt"
      METADATA
         ows_title "Urbane zone 2012"
         ows_abstract "rezolucija 25 cm"
         wms_extent "6304500 4709990 6635000 5027700" #Can use the map level extent values
      END
      TEMPLATE "blank.html"
   END
END
```

In QGIS I tried "Ignore axis orientation" options, but it doesn't help.

I am running MapServer on Windows Server 2012 R2, SSD disk, CPU i7-4790K, RAM 32GB. Raster files are on WD 3TB Green HDD.

Comment: Why don't you put a PROJECTION for the layer?

Comment: I added PROJECTION "init=epsg:3908" END to the layer, but still same error

Comment: Using VRT in GeoServer is very slow, because it is not a native implementation, but uses GDAL reader. You could try to use the Imagemosaic extension which should be very good in your case. http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html

Comment: Do GetCapabilities and include the part about layer "Urbane zone 2012". BTW. while layer names with spaces are valid in WMS they tend to make trouble sometimes.

Comment: @RoVo, this is MapServer even your comment about VRT is right. With small number of files it is OK but the native way in MapServer is to use tileindex.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Can you please provide me a link how to setup MapServer to use tileindex?

Comment: Search "mapserver + tileindex" and you will find this http://www.mapserver.org/optimization/tileindex.html.

Comment: Is is slow always or is is fast when you zoom close but slow when you zoom far? Showing the full scene means that server must open more that 7000 files and that will be slow with any server. You must use a separate layer with less source files for that situation. Normal recipe is to make the layers scale dependent and collect them into WMS group layer.